# Is there any reference for LINUX and cross-platforms APIs?

Tags: c++, linux, api

First, I develope C++ applications that invokes OS APIs (like CopyFile, GetModuleFileName, ... in Windows). I don't want to develope GUI applications. my applications work like a SERVICE or CONSOLE in WINDOWS.

Second, Standard C++ Libraries doesn't provide advance programming features like Threads, Network and even File Management.

In MS Windows platform, MSDN provides very good reference for C++ programmers that want to work with Windows APIs.

For example in this page: "[EncodePointer Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432254%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)", MSDN describes that EncodePointer is an API that "Minimum supported client is Windows Vista, Windows XP with SP2", "DLL
 is Kernel32.dll" and ...

Now I want to start LINUX programming. I found too many libraries and references, some work in Fedora, some work in Ubunto, some work in SUSE and...

BUT I want **ONE LIBRARY** that works in **ALL LINUX distributes**. Something like Windows API that **works in ALL WINDOWSes**.

Is there any library that I write code once for linux? and don't worry about other distributes of LINUX?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a standard that should work (other than minor bugs or a few things that aren't implemented) across most Unix-type systems, including all Linux distros, the BSDs, Solaris, AIX, and so on. It's called [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) or the [Single Unix Specification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_UNIX_Specification); they are both basically equivalent, but published by different groups. You have to pay for POSIX, but the Single Unix Specification is [available online for free](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/).

Note that some of POSIX is implemented on Windows, and there are systems like [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) or [Windows Services for Unix/Subsystem for Unix Applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Services_for_UNIX) to add more complete support of POSIX to Windows, though these generally require downloading separate libraries and runtime components, and can sometimes be frustrating work work with as things like line endings and file permissions work differently in Windows and Unix based APIs.

Beyond POSIX, Linux and glibc implement some system calls and library routines of their own, so if you're only interested in running on Linux and not other Unix-like operating systems, you have a somewhat richer API to work with. If you know what call you're looking for, you can use the [`man`](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/man1.html) command on Linux to find documentation on it; system calls (like `fork` or `execve`) are documented in section 2, and library calls (like `printf`) are documented in section 3. Man pages can also be found online in a variety of places, such as [the Linux man-pages project](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/dir_all_by_section.html) . There is also a complete [online manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html) for glibc, and [an online reference of Linux system calls](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/syscalls.2.html).

If you want a book on the topic, [The Linux Programming Interface](http://man7.org/tlpi/) by Michael Kerrisk, the guy who runs the Linux man-pages project, is supposed to be quite good.

For a reference on what should be supported across all distributions of Linux, you can take a look at the [Linux Standard Base](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/lsb.shtml). Like POSIX, this is generally mostly supported on most distributions of Linux; there will be some minor deviations here and there, but on the whole it should tell you what's expected of a modern Linux. The Linux Standard Base mostly references other standards, like the Single Unix Specification/POSIX or the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard, but describes some Linux-specific functionality itself.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you want the [POSIX library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_POSIX_library).

Comment: Do you mean, all LINUX distributes fully support POSIX library? It sounds great.

Comment: @Amir: No. Linux supports *most* of POSIX, but does certain things a different way; see the corresponding man pages in sections 2 and 3p for the differences.

Comment: Linux distributions are mostly POSIX compliment (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX#Mostly_POSIX-compliant) in practice the are compient enough that you need not worry if you are doing fairly standard stuff with files, sockets and threads. If you hunt corner cases you may find differences in the *nix world espically between bsd and linux.

Comment: Does windows suppots POSIX? If Windows supports POSIX, It seems I can write once source code for both LINUX and Windows.

Comment: Windows used to have a whole POSIX *subsystem* (kinda like the "console" and "windows" subsystems) to ease compatibility of *nix apps to Windows.  AFAIK, though, they've always lacked some essential features.  Namely `fork()`.

Comment: @Amir No, Windows doesn't support POSIX. It has support for parts of POSIX, and you can add support for most of POSIX using systems like [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) or Microsoft's [Windows Services for UNIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Services_for_UNIX), but they are both extra libraries and run-time systems that you would have to distribute along with your application or otherwise get people to install.

Answer (score 2):

Leaving the fact that each version of Windows provides a slightly different API aside for the moment, each Linux distribution supports programming to glibc, the documentation of which is contained in section 2 of the man pages.

Answer (score 2):

[Qt](http://qt.nokia.com) is a good framework that can be used to develop once and compiled for all platforms including Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Try BOOST
http://www.boost.org/

Comment: Boost is a limited library. For example there is no any way to access the name of the current user in boost.